# Vector within struct within class

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector, struct

So, I have this struct:

```
struct Articol
{
vector <char*> Nume;
char* Titlu;
int An;
vector <int> Pagini;
};
```

and this class:

```
class Bibliografie
{
int nr_art, nr_carti, nr_pagini;
vector <Articol> Articole;
};
```

and the following line of code:

```
cout << Object.Articole.Nume[j] << " ";
```

that generates this error:

```
error: ‘class std::vector<Articol>’ has no member named ‘Nume’
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Articole` is a `std::vector` and `std::vector` has no member `Nume`. The error is very clear. You need to get an element from the `std::vector` `Articole`:

```
Object.Articole[x].Nume[j]
```

Just make sure that element at index `x` exists (or use `.at(` or iterators or anything else, see [`std::vector` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)).

Comment: Yeap, I have just figured that out. Dumb me..Thanks!

Comment: @epanicafrate no problem, feel free to mark as the correct answer.